# Java misising library in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation

Tags: java, jar

I am not sure where to ask this, but I will try it here: I searched half a day (that is: downloaded and searched thru its content) ALL the org.springframework.web.servlet jars from the very first release (2.5.6) till the latest one (3.2.2) but I am unable to find/locate one specific library that should be there called "CorsRegistry.java" (org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry).

This specific library is needed for the ["Document Viewer Java Library"](https://github.com/groupdocs-viewer/GroupDocs.Viewer-for-Java) (beside quantum of many other jars).

Can anyone point me to the correct download location of the file that would include this specific library?

Comment: Check spring-webmvc-XXX.jar.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask such questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Khanna111 yes, that solved the issue - it is located there, thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see this class in the latest [`spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.19)

```
-> jar -tf spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar  | grep "CorsRegistry"
org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistry.class
```

Comment: yes,  as @Khanna111 already told me, but I will make this correct answer as well...thank you. Just rename the jar name as first I was mislead you are really talking about the web tho it is webmvc instead.